# Spring-Kafka cannot convert AVRO GenericData.Record to Acknowledgment

Tags: json, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, avro

Using Spring Boot, I am trying to set up my Kafka consumers in batch receiving mode:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericData.Record> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericData.Record> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter()); // I know this one won't work
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<GenericData.Record, GenericData.Record> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> dataRiverProps = getDataRiverProps();
    dataRiverProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("bootstrap.servers"));
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(dataRiverProps);
}
```

And this is what the actual consumer looks like:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.topics}'.split(',')}", containerFactory = 'kafkaListenerContainerFactory')
public void consumeAvro(List<GenericData.Record> list, Acknowledgment ack) {
    messageProcessor.addMessageBatchToExecutor(list);
    while (messageProcessor.getTaskSize() > EXECUTOR_TASK_COUNT_THRESHOLD) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER_ERROR.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e.getCause()));
        }
    }
}
```

The exceptions I am getting look like this:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record] to type [org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:46)
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191)
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174)
        at org.springframework.messaging.converter.GenericMessageConverter.fromMessage(GenericMessageConverter.java:66)
```

The Kafka messages are AVRO messages, and I would like to retrieve them as JSON strings. Is there a ready-for-use AVRO converter for GenericData.Record that I can plug in the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory? Thanks!

Comment: So this is what I have found. If I remove Acknowledgement from the signature then it will work just fine:  public void consumeAvro(List<Message<GenericData.Record>> list) { ...} I was hoping to be able to manually commit, as you can see from my original post I was trying to throttle the consumer. So if I don't manually acknowledge by calling ack.acknowledge() after the while loop, does it mean that it will automatically acknowledge after the while loop, as well as acknowledge regularly based on the auto.commit.interval.ms setting? Thanks!

Comment: Can someone point me to some example to show I can possibly implement a message converter for GenericData.Record? Thanks!

Comment: do you want to convert  to GenericData.Record POJO?

Comment: Thanks @Prabhakar! I really have no idea where to even start. If someone can even show me an example that will be very helpful!

Comment: sure I will create an example.

Comment: if you are still looking for sample program, please see below answer

Answer (score 12):

Just add below property to your kafka consumer configs

props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true");

Comment: Only to complete a little bit this answer, if you have your config in a properties file, the equivalent one for this would be `spring.kafka.properties.specific.avro.reader: true`

Comment: @gualizoe you are my saviour, dude!

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example of how to consume messages in batch mode.

[Sample Kafka demo for Batch listener with avro message formart](https://github.com/prabhakar349/kafkademo)

The App has a Custom Message Convertor which converts Avro messages to Pojo directly.It uses Schema files in the classPath. The schema files are named with convention "topicName".avsc

```
public class AvroSchemaMessageConverter extends MessagingMessageConverter {

  private AvroMapper avroMapper;
  private SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry;
  private KafkaHeaderMapper headerMapper;


  public AvroSchemaMessageConverter(AvroMapper avroMapper, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry) {
    this.avroMapper = avroMapper;
    this.schemaRegistry = schemaRegistry;
    if (JacksonPresent.isJackson2Present()) {
      this.headerMapper = new DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper();
    } else {
      this.headerMapper = new SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected Object extractAndConvertValue(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Type type) {
    System.out.printf(record.value().getClass().getName());
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap((byte[])record.value());
    JavaType javaType = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(type);
    try {
      return avroMapper.readerFor(javaType).with(schemaRegistry.getAvroSchema(record.topic()))
        .readValue(buffer.array(), buffer.arrayOffset(), buffer.limit());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new ConversionException("Failed to convert AvroMessage", e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public ProducerRecord<?, ?> fromMessage(Message<?> message, String defaultTopic) {
    MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
    Object topicHeader = headers.get(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC);
    String topic = null;
    if (topicHeader instanceof byte[]) {
      topic = new String(((byte[]) topicHeader), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } else if (topicHeader instanceof String) {
      topic = (String) topicHeader;
    } else if (topicHeader == null) {
      Assert.state(defaultTopic != null, "With no topic header, a defaultTopic is required");
    } else {
      throw new IllegalStateException(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC + " must be a String or byte[], not "
        + topicHeader.getClass());
    }
    String actualTopic = topic == null ? defaultTopic : topic;
    Integer partition = headers.get(KafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID, Integer.class);
    Object key = headers.get(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY);
    Object payload = convertPayload(message, topic);
    Long timestamp = headers.get(KafkaHeaders.TIMESTAMP, Long.class);
    Headers recordHeaders = initialRecordHeaders(message);
    if (this.headerMapper != null) {
      this.headerMapper.fromHeaders(headers, recordHeaders);
    }
    return new ProducerRecord(topic == null ? defaultTopic : topic, partition, timestamp, key,
      payload,
      recordHeaders);
  }

  protected Object convertPayload(Message<?> message, String topic) {
    try {
      return avroMapper.writer(schemaRegistry.getAvroSchema(topic))
        .writeValueAsBytes(message.getPayload());
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      throw new ConversionException("Failed to convert object to AvroMessage", e);
    }
  }
```

Here is how we need to configure ConsumerFactory and KafkaListenerContainerFactory:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Object>>
  kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory =
      new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    factory.setBatchListener(true); // This is needed for batch listener
    factory.setMessageConverter(new BatchMessagingMessageConverter(converter()));
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
    return factory;

  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory) {
    KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<String, Object>(producerFactory);
    kafkaTemplate.setMessageConverter(converter());
    return kafkaTemplate;
  }

  @Bean
  public RecordMessageConverter converter() {
    return new AvroSchemaMessageConverter(avroMapper(), schemaRegistry());
  }

  @Bean
  public SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry() {
    return new SchemaRegistry();
  }

  @Bean
  public AvroMapper avroMapper() {
    AvroMapper mapper = new AvroMapper();
    mapper.configure(Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN, true);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    return mapper;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question @Prabhakar! This is really helpful! One more question I have. What if the AVRO schema changes? Does it mean that as long as the new schema is backward-compatible, i don't have to change my code? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes schema changes should be backward compatible.If there is a need to make breaking changes, the best way is to create new topic for that.

Comment: Thanks @Prabhakar! Really appreciate it!